# Software to visualize multidimensional large datasets

Tags: data-visualization

What software is able to do this kind of multidimensional visualizations on large datasets?
Interactive multidimensional parallel coordinates mixed with splom or other methods to analyze multidimensional data.
[image: Screenshot Flowviz]

I wasn't able to find any software called FlowVizMenu.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9Z0mPOnG_M

I think Ggobi or Mondrian are not so powerful.

I would also like to know where can I download sample files with multidimensional data, either categorical or quantitative, for example meteorological or any health study.

Comment: The downloading part of your question is not on topic here, but could be asked at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/.